# Provisioning exception in eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I am facing this error while checking for updates in eclipse ADT.

Provisioning exception

No repository found at http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` 
Eclipse will prompt that the content isn't authorized. Ignore it and continue.

If it does not work then `go to eclipse.ini` file (you will find it within eclipse installation directory).

Add this line after `-vmargs`

```
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```